# Смысл функции hash() в HashMap (java 7 и java 8)

Tags: java, хеширование

В Java 7 функция hash() класса HashMap имеет следующий вид:

```
/**
  * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
  * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
  * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
  * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
  * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
  */
static int hash(int h) {
        // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
        // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
        // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

Из всего этого я понимаю только первый комментарий (перед функцией). 
Данная функция используется "на всякий случай" - в случае, если hashCode объекта будет плохой ("низкого качества"), то данная функция должна обеспечить лучший разброс значений. Это важно, потому что HashMap использует хэш-таблицы, размер которых - степень двойки (16, 32, 64 и т.д.), и в противном случае, при использовании хэш-кодов, у которых в младших битах есть совпадения (при использовании хэш-функций "низкого качества") возникают коллизии.

А что значит комментарий внутри функции?

> This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by constant
>   multiples at each bit position have a bounded number of collisions
>   (approximately 8 at default load factor).

И в чём собственно смысл преобразований функции?

```
h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
```

Почему побитовые сдвиги и XOR - понятно, потому что данные операции выполняются быстрее, чем операции сложения и умножения. Но почему именно эти цифры (20, 12, 7, 4)? И каким образом эти преобразования делают более разнообразными младшие биты хэш-кодов?

И почему в Java 8 эта функция изменилась следующим образом?

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
   int h;
   return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

В чём её смысл? Часть `(key == null) ? 0 :` вопросов не вызывает.

Comment: Doug Lea [пишет](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-January/030748.html), что в предрелизных тестах jdk-8 старая функция была видимо, но не значительно, медленнее новой на строковых, целых и identity-хэш ключах, которые, по имевшимся старым данным, составляют 90% всех использований HashMap. Поскольку древофикация (деревизация?) снизила остроту проблемы с недостаточным разнообразием в младших битах хэша (напр. для целых чисел в формате с плавающей точкой), замена была проведена.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы понять зачем `HashMap` модифицирует хеш объекта, нужно заглянуть под капот этого `HashMap`. Указанный ассоциативный массив реализуется через ***бакеты***. `HashMap` состоит из массива таких бакетов, к которым можно обращаться по ***индексу***. Количество бакетов - это всегда результат возведения `2` в какую-то степень (`2, 4, 8, 16` и т.д.). Каждый из бакетов представляет из себя коллекцию (список или дерево). Хорошее распределение по `HashMap` - это когда каждый из бакетов содержит примерно одинаковое количество записей (пар ключ-значение)

Теперь к сути. При записи нового объекта **сначала ищется бакет**, в который будет производиться запись. Для этого берется **остаток от деления хеша на количество бакетов** (своего рода хеш от хеша). Это и будет ***индекс*** бакета, в который попадёт новый элемент. Для наглядности, операцию остаток от деления на результат степени 2-х (а это количество бакетов) можно представить в виде *поразрядного И* `хеша` и `(количество_бакетов - 1)` , т.е.:

```
хэш % количество_бакетов = хэш & (количество_бакетов - 1)
```

Для примера покажу в двоичном варианте, где хэш равен `140`, а количество бакетов `32` (результат должен быть равен `12`):

```
10001100 % 0010000 = 10001100 & 00011111 = 00001100
```

Тут и выползает интересная особенность. ***На то, в какой бакет попадёт новая запись, влияют только младшие биты хеша***. При реальных условиях количество бакетов обычно невысокое (к примеру 8192 вмещается в 14 битов) . А хеш имеет тип `int`, т.е. аж **32 бита!!!**.

***Поэтому и придумали различными манипуляциями подмешивать старшие биты хэша в младшие, чтобы улучшить распределение по бакетам и, как следствие, производительность.***

Comment: То, что Вы описали (поиск индекса бакета), - это работа функции `indexFor` (если говорить про java 7). И как работает эта функция, мне вполне понятно. Мне непонятен смысл именно функции `hash(int h)`. Не понятно именно то, зачем "подмешивать старшие биты хэша в младшие" - ведь по сути в первоначальном хэше (параметре, который приходит на вход функции `hash(int h)` старшие и младшие биты будут скорее всего одинаково равнозначные...

Comment: И в java хеш имеет тип int, а не long, и это 32 бита, а не 64)

Comment: Ну и операция получения остатка от деления на результат степени 2-х (на количество бакетов) представляется в виде поразрядного И не для наглядности, а из соображений производительности, потому что побитовые операции быстрее)

Comment: @Ksenia касательно `long` я ошибся, т.к. писал по памяти. Как я говорил `На то, в какой бакет попадёт новая запись, влияют только младшие биты хеша`. Потому и придумана функция дополнительная функция `hash` внутри `HashMap`, чтобы старшие биты родного хеша объекта начали вносить коррективы в то, в какой бакет попадёт объект.